# Have other elements observe the position of a fixed element

Tags: css

I am trying to build a page with two tables. One table is a small "key" and I want it to always remain visible even after scrolling, which is required by the 2nd much larger table. I can accomplish the key table positioning with "position: fixed" I would like the 2nd "results" table to be positioned just to the right of the "key" table without specifying the exact pixel position for the left edge. I've tried applying CSS positioning to a DIV around the second table, as well as directly to the table (position:relative float:left) but keep getting the result of the two tables being on top of each other. Also tried applying z-index:0 to both elements. I only delve into page construction on a part time basis. I've tried reviewing several CSS positioning guides and cannot figure this out.
Thanks

Update:

Thanks to both... understanding that "fixed" broke the flow was key that was not obvious from CSS positioning doc I read. Knowing that, I used "margin-left:150px" on the 2nd table to keep it from colliding with the first.

[image: diagram]

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<div style="position:fixed; top:10px; left:10px;">
<table>
<tr><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr>
<tr><td>Thing1</td><td>Meaning1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Thing2</td><td>Meaning3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Thing3</td><td>Meaning3</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<div style="position:relative; float: left;">
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th></th>Group<th></th></tr>
<tr><td>Name1</td><td>Group1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name2</td><td>Group2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name3</td><td>Group3</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a way to do this purely with CSS, as `position:fixed` removes that element from the document flow. However, JavaScript would be a great solution. Are you open to that idea?

Answer (score 1):

You have a key table that has `fixed` positioning. This will break it out of the flow. You still need an element that keeps your `float: left;` div from underlapping.

I'd do:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 30%;">&nbsp;
    <div style="position: fixed; ...">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 70%;>
    <table...>...</table>
</div>
```

Here's a example: http://jsfiddle.net/1rqarona/1/

Comment: The fixed element is still removed from the document flow and they still overlap. http://jsfiddle.net/wwonwL1j/

Comment: @showdev simply adding some content (I added a `&nbsp;`) will force the floated div to take up the correct size. This answer is a concept. Of course OP will want to edit the widths to his content.

Comment: Your edit works better, but you still have to specify the percentage widths. It seems that the OP wants this to work without specifying the width of the left element. I could be wrong about that. http://jsfiddle.net/1rqarona/2/

Comment: Hmm, I can't really see a pure-CSS way of making that left column auto-width since fixing the child's position will break it out of style flow.